# Android Button with Drawable - Padding

Tags: java, android, button, drawable, padding

I want to add a Drawable Image to my Button on the left and tried the following:

```
button = new Button(this);
button.setWidth(screen_dimens(0.25, "w")); //25% of screen width
button.setPadding(5, 5, 0, 5);
Drawable img = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(img, null, null, null);
```

But I want to have a padding on the left between the drawable and the border of the button. Unfortunately, there is none. 
Any help?

Comment: Can you not set the left padding to a larger value?

Comment: I tried with 15 - but no difference

Comment: Well, okay, it just seems impossible. Everything I try fails. I think I'll just add a transparent padding to the image-file.
But I'm open to any further ideas :)

Comment: For the sake of anyone else reading this, if you set the 'padding' attribute, it will do what you want.  But the paddingTop, paddingRight, etc attributes don't correctly override the parent and also do not have the same effect.  So that hack might work for some people in some situations, but it wasn't applicable for me.

Answer (score 5):

This will generate text + image button ( Image on Left & Text After That )

```
   <Button
   android:gravity="center_vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
   android:id="@+id/button2"
   android:paddingLeft="20dp"
   style="@style/whiteText"
   android:onClick="openWhyAshoka"
   android:drawableLeft="@drawable/arrow"
   android:drawablePadding="50dp"
   android:text="Ankit" />
```

Comment: I gave it my best and this solution didn't work for me.  Are you sure it works?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the padding to you drawable, by changing the 9 slices content area or by changing your drawable padding:

```
<padding
    android:bottom="10dp"
    android:left="10dp"
    android:right="10dp"
    android:top="10dp" />
```

If you are using selector you have to add the padding rule to each one of the drawable states.

Comment: AFAIK this is the only answer that does not involve code.  While the OP didn't specifically state that that's what he wanted, it is what I'm looking for.  Android needs to fix this :(

Answer (score 1):

Use this API call:

```
public void setCompoundDrawablePadding (int pad)
```

Comment: but I think this adds padding between the drawable and the text. This is not what I want

Answer (score 1):

Use this Code:

```
Drawable image = (Drawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.onstar_mute_unmute_button_selector);

ImageButton button=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

button.setPadding(0,10,5,0);

button.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

button.setBackground(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <Button
            android:id="@+id/otherapps"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
            android:text="@string/other_apps"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="cursive"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_more"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp" //for drawable padding to the left
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
```